# ssh keys from mac to ubuntu 12 lts

Tags: ubuntu, ssh, ssh-keys

I am attempting to set up a scenario in which I do not require to submit a password to ssh into an ubuntu machine from a mac. This is procedure i have been following:

1 - Open a terminal in your mac and remain logged in as you, not root.

2 - `ssh-keygen`  (when asked for a password leave blank, the purpose of this s for rsync to be able to ssh without a password prompt)

3 - `cat ~/.ssh/id_rsa.pub`

This will have made an SSH key which will now be living in your home folder. 
Now you need to add the public key into the ubuntu VM

1 – Login as root into the vm

2 – `mkdir /home/john/.ssh/`

3  - `nano /home/john/.ssh/authorized_keys`
    copy the key generated on you mac into the ida_rsa.pub and paste into this file

4 – `chown –R john /home/john/.ssh/`

5 – `chmod 600 /home/john`

The result of this is, I have the key in both home directories. But when i `ssh john@local.mysite.com` i still get asked for a pword..

Any ideas?

Is there a config that must be setup in ssh within the ubuntu machine to allow this behaviour to happen?

Comment: Can we see the output of `ls -la ~john/.ssh` on the ubuntu box?  Paste it into your question, that way the formatting will be retained.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here's the problem:

```
chmod 600 /home/john
```

You're making your home directory non-executable for yourself, which means that any process owned by you can't enter the directory to read its contents - including your ssh keys.

You want `chmod 700 /home/john` instead. Also `chmod 700 /home/john/.ssh; chmod 600 /home/john/.ssh/*`